# FusionAuth Setup Wizard issue

Tags: fusionauth

I have attempted to install the Fusionauth using installing the package guide, I went through the steps with no issues until the last step to add the administrator account and when provided all required information I got this message "A request to the search index has failed. This error is unexpected. Contact Support."

here is the log file "fusionauth-search.log"

> [Sep 30, 2019 11:54:30.674 AM][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 25gb[5.2%], shards will be relocated away from this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 11:54:30.699 AM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] rerouting shards: [high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes]
>   [Sep 30, 2019 11:55:00.707 AM][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 25gb[5.2%], shards will be relocated away from this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 12:17:31.739 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 57.4gb[12%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 12:31:02.531 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 57.4gb[12%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 12:58:33.948 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 62.1gb[13%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 12:59:03.982 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 62.5gb[13.1%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 12:59:34.016 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 63.2gb[13.2%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:00:04.027 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 63.3gb[13.3%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:00:34.039 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 63.4gb[13.3%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:01:04.047 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 63.6gb[13.3%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:01:34.056 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 63.7gb[13.4%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:02:04.067 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 63.9gb[13.4%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:02:34.074 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 64.1gb[13.4%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:03:04.083 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 64.2gb[13.5%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:03:34.120 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 64.4gb[13.5%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:04:04.131 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 64.6gb[13.5%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:04:34.141 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 65.2gb[13.7%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:05:04.175 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 65.3gb[13.7%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:05:34.184 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 65.5gb[13.7%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:06:04.194 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 65.6gb[13.7%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:06:34.224 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 65.7gb[13.8%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:07:04.234 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 66.4gb[13.9%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:07:34.245 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 67.4gb[14.1%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:08:04.254 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 68gb[14.3%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:08:34.262 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 69gb[14.5%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:09:04.272 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 67.4gb[14.1%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:09:34.281 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [ZVTSlmh1STaZOSQAo6UiQg][ZVTSlmh][C:\FusionAuthDir\fusionauth\fusionauth-search\elasticsearch....\data\search\esv6\nodes\0] free: 68.3gb[14.3%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
>   [Sep 30, 2019 1:10:04.314 PM][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ZVTSlmh] rerouting shards: [one or more nodes has gone under the high or low watermark]

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [low disk watermark \[??%\] exceeded on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369955/low-disk-watermark-exceeded-on)

Comment: where is that yml file that I have to edit

Comment: This doesn't look to be a FusionAuth issue, @Stphane looks to be on the money.