# How to restore elasticsearch s3 snapshot on a different cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elastic Cloud on Kubernetes (ECK) setup and i have also setup snapshots which are stored on s3.

I want to restore these snapshots on s3 to a local version of ECK i have running on minikube. So how do i restore snapshots that are on s3 to a different (local) elastic search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restore an elasticsearch s3 snapshot on a different cluster i just simply registered the s3 snapshot on the second cluster as read only and it was able to find the s3 backups then you can restore from there.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-register-repository.html

After restoring from the snapshot, the cluster/index statuses may go to red and you can follow advise on here to restore that back to normal [low disk watermark [??%] exceeded on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369955/low-disk-watermark-exceeded-on)

Comment: Suppose I have an NFS server, should every node be connected to that server? Can I have 3 different nfs servers one for each node for my backup repositories?